Can anyone please explain why the second answer is different from the other 3?
Here I apply the same formulas to the function $e^{-x}$ and its truncated power series. Why the second result is so different?


You should tag this with the name of the software you are using, and include it in the title, to avoid wasting people's time. This is technically not about math, or summation, or regularization, it is about the specifics of a particular software's programming language.

@ThomasAndrews this is Wolfram Mathematica, but it is obviously not about specifics of the software as I do not suspect any bugs.

Put it in the question. People reading the title want to know if they can help you, and if they don't know Mathematica, you might be wasting their time. Tag it, put it in the title, and put it in the question.

It clearly is a bug, whether in your code or in Mathematica. Again, try to not waste the time of people who might think they can help you. A person who doesn't know Mathematica has no way to read this question.

@ThomasAndrews I am sure, it would be the case in any computer algebra system.

I am sorry you think making an effort to help people help you is beneath you. You could have taken just a moment to edit your question, but instead, you chose to ignore advice from a person who has been here a little while, denying even that it could help to let people know you are asking about software.

@ThomasAndrews man, this is a math, not a CAS question. I asked it at Mathematica SE though and it was received better, even though it is pure math. It is not about Mathematica really. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/309646/equivalence-of-a-function-to-its-truncated-power-series

Keep digging in your heals. It is sure to win friends and influence people.
